# Suggested data types for MySQL table holding user registrations?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a site in PHP,

I have come up with these MySQL data types to use in the user registration table. Do these look ok or are there better data types that can be used?

```
id                          INT(100)
email                       VARCHAR(100)
password                    VARCHAR(100)
nickname                    VARCHAR(30)
registration_date           DATE()
lastlogon_date              DATE()
```

Email is obviously an e-mail address, password is an encrypted string created by PHP `password_hash()` and nickname is a user chosen nickname that can be up to 30 characters long, but isn't neccasarily 30 characters long.

Thanks
Jack

Comment: `DATE()` is not a MySQL data type.

Comment: looks good to me if it runs with date

Comment: the length of a password hash is constant, so there is no need to use a varchar. I prefer to use int to store dates, because I don't have to think about what timezone mysql is configured with.

Comment: until you want to use date functions that are rather rich ? I guess there are other homegrown date libraries one can use with int. But not much support with questions about them for sql noobs

Comment: Isn't `date` a function?

Comment: i think it was a typo Script

Comment: `password  VARCHAR(100)` if and when you use a 21st century password hashing method such as password_hash() it's best to use 255. The manual even suggests it.

Comment: @Drew Date is a data type as per http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.htm

Comment: @Jack, `Date` is a date type. `Date()` is not. In other words, look at your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine except your 'id' columns size looks too large. You didnt mention how you were going to create the id's but if you use AI (auto increment) and start a 1 or even 100, `INT(100)` seems to be an over kill. Think about it, your id starts at 1 & AI to even 10 decimal places or 10,000,000,000 ids. `INT(10)` or id seems sufficient if you think youll have less than 10 billion users/ids.

Everything else looks good. I hope this helps!

Comment: int(11) for instance is a display issue. the storage capacity is still 4 bytes